# How to solve PL/Sql Function compilation error

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have two table .one from server and another from host.I have to union them and count total donor by gender.I tried to run this function.But It shows error.How can I solve it?

```
**create or replace function count_donor_by_gender(g in Donor.gender%TYPE)
    return number
    is
    
    g_donor number:=0;
    
begin

    FOR R IN (select *  from Donor@site_link union Donor) LOOP
        if(R.gender=g) then
            g_donor:=g_donor+1;
        end if;
    END LOOP;
    
    return g_donor;

end count_donor_by_gender;
/**
```

[image: Compilation Error]

Comment: Hi. What does the error say?

Comment: Missing Select Keyword and sql statement ignored...I have added a pic

Comment: I have two table .one from server and another from host.I have to union them and count total donor by gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
select *  from Donor@site_link union Donor
```

The "union" statement append results of 2 SELECT statements into one, so you need to

```
select *  from Donor@site_link union select * from Donor
```

Please be aware that "UNION" causes database to remove duplicates which may degrade the performance. If removing duplicates was not intented, use "UNION ALL" instead